# How do I work globally on a complex data structure using subroutines?

Tags: perl

Specifically my data structure looks like this

```
{
  "SomeGuy" => {
    date_and_time => "11-04-2013",
    Id => 7,
    nr => 52,
    picks => [
      { "This is an option" => "Option3" },
      { "This is another option" => "Option4" },
      { "This is another option" => "Option1" },
      { "And another one" => "Something" },
    ],
    time_of => "06:11 AM",
    total => 1,
  },
  "Another Guy" => { ... },
}
```

This is output via [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDump). The actual data structure contains a lot more records like `"SomeGuy"`. The structure is identical for all of them.

I populate this data structure this way:

```
$guys->{$profile}{options}[$total++]{$var} = $var2;
$guys->{$profile}{Id} = $i;
$guys->{$profile}{date_and_time} = get_date($Time[0]);
$guys->{$profile}{time_of} = $Time[1];
$guys->{$profile}{total} = keys (% {$guys->{$profile}{options}[0]});
$guys->{$profile}{nr} = $pNr;
```

Having all this, what I want to do next is operate on this data structure. I repeat that there many many records in the data structure.

When I output the contents of it I get it in jumbled order, as to say, not in the order that it was populated. I've tried this with [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper), `Data::Dump` and iterating through the records myself by hand.

I know that the methods in the `Data` namespace are notorious for this, that's why `Data::Dumper` provides a way to sort through a subroutine and `Data::Dump` provides a default one.

So I have the data structure. It looks like I expect it to be, I have all the data as I knew it should look in it, valid. I want to sort the records according to their `Id` field. My thinking is that I have to use a subroutine and essentially pass a reference of the data structure to it and do the sorting there.

```
 sub sortt {
    my $dref = shift @_;
    foreach my $name ( sort { $dref->{$a}{Id} <=> $dref->{$b}{Id} } keys %$dref ) {
      print "$data->{$name}{Id}: $name \n";
    }
 }
```

This gets called with (in the same scope where the structure is populated, so no worries there):

```
 sortt(\$guys);
```

The error is:

```
 Not a HASH reference at perlprogram.pl line 452
```

So I go and use `ref` in the subroutine to make sure I'm passing an actual reference. And it says `REF`.

Next I go into desperate mode and try some stupid things like calling it with:

```
sortt(\%$guys)
```

But if I'm not mistaking this just sends a copy to the subroutine and just sorts that copy locally, so no use there.

It's no use if I make a copy and return it from the subroutine, I just want to pass a reference of my data structure and sort it and have it reflect those changes globally (or in the calling scope per se). How would I do this?

Comment: You are sorting the keys, but all you do with the sorted keys is print them. You want to change the order of the *hash's elements*, but that's not possible. You really should learn what a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$guys` is already a hash ref, so you just need `sortt($guys)`

If you want a sorted data structure, you need something like this:

```
my @guys_sorted =
    map  { { $_ => $guys->{$_} } }
    sort { $guys->{$a}{Id} <=> $guys->{$b}{Id} } keys %$guys;

print(Dumper(\@guys_sorted));
```

Or, in a sub:

```
sub sortt {
    # returns a SORTED ARRAY of HASHREFS
    my $ref = shift;
    return map  { { $_ => $ref->{$_} } }
           sort { $ref->{$a}{Id} <=> $ref->{$b}{Id} } keys %$ref;
}

print(Dumper([sortt($guys)]));
```

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't sort it. Both Data::Dumper and going through it by hand output it in the unordered fashion. I know the sortt sub is right because I print it locally and it does put it in the right order.

Comment: Put what in the right order? Are you saying `sortt` is suppose to alter the data structure? Cause it doesn't even attempt to do that right now

Comment: The keys, the "Guys". I want them to be ordered in ascending order as per their "Id" value. I want to have all of my structure ordered by that value and change everything else, not just the keys at some level.

Comment: Are you saying you want to order the underlying structure? If so, you must convert your hash to an array since a hash is an unordered data structure.

Comment: Yes I think that's what I mean. To put it other words I want to order the keys at the first level by their Id field and thus have all of the other fields succumb to that change as well. Basically move the keys around with everything else they have. Is there a way to do this without altering the structure of it all?

Comment: Okay, see updated answer. Perl hashes are ordered by the hash of the key, so you must choose an ordered data structure such as an array.

Comment: It's imperative that I keep the keys. I tried the code you just put in and it does sort the values of the first-level hash but it also dumps the keys when you create the array. Obviously my grip with perl data types is lacking enough but is there a way for me to move the values manually in my initial data structure? Basically recreate the hash on the spot in what I would assume would be a nested foreach or something like that.

Comment: Okay I understand what you are asking for. What you need to do is add the key (name) to the data structure. I will post an update momentarily.

Comment: You can NOT sort them because $guys is a hash, not an array. Hashes are **NOT** ever sorted in Perl. If you want to sort it, store an ordered list of names as a separate array

Comment: But is there a way to maintain the same spot for the "name" field as opposed to just having it as another field in the array hash element? Or is that just going back to the problem there was before? Essentially just having an array of hashes to hashes as opposed to an array of hashes.

Comment: This is a ridiculous suggestion. It creates an array of single-element hashes.

Comment: @Borodin that is often more convenient than having a hash and a separate array giving the desired order of keys

Comment: @codnodder: My comment and downvote are *"informed"* insofar as I have read all of your edits and the comments that the OP made. As far as I can tell, the OP needs a data structure that involves both the original hash and an associated sorted array of keys. The implementation you have described requires an unnecessary dereference, and it should really be a simple array of hashes with the `name` as an additional field. It also has the disadvantage that the sort order is fixed, whereas a simple hash plus an array of keys can be accessed in any order.

Comment: @codnodder: The way Stack Overflow works is that the *net* votes are what is relevant. Your answer has received *zero* upvotes and one downvote, and I believe it is misleading and wrong. There are two answers with a *positive* net total, and I agree with both of them. I believe the OP has a problem understand how to access his data in diffrent ways, and what you have suggested will only pander to his misunderstanding, while unnecessarily *duplicating* his data structure in a awkward fashion.

Comment: @ysth: I would like to see an example of that

Answer (score 4):

Leaving aside your syntax problem with "Not a ref", you are approaching the problem from the wrong end in the first place. I'll leave small syntactic details to others (see Ikegami's comment).

You can NOT sort them at all, because `$guys` is a *hash*, not an array. Hashes are *NOT* ever sorted in Perl. If you want to sort it, your have three solutions:

1. Store an ordered list of names as a separate array.

   `my @ordered_names = sort { $guys->{$a}{Id} <=> $guys->{$b}{Id} } keys %$guys`

   Then you use the array for ordering and go back to hashref for individual records.
2. Add the name to the individual guy's hash, instead of outer hash reference. `$guys` should be an array reference. The downside to this approach is that you can't look up a person's record by their name any more - if that functionality is needed, use #1.

   @codnodder's answer shows how to do that, if you don't care about accessing records by name.
3. Use a `Tie::*` module. ([`Tie::IxHash`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aIxHash), [`Tie::Hash::Sorted`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aHash%3a%3aSorted)). NOT recommended since it's slower.

Comment: Like I said I really need the accessing by name key functionality. While googling around I did find people mentioning the Tie::* namespace but the problem is I really need to stick with base Perl (or plus more common Modules). It is alredy slow just processed plainly like this. Your first option would've been obvious had I known of hashes unordered property up front. To my excuse the stupid syntactic mistake must've completely clouded my judgement.

Comment: @user3046061, ah, so you're asking us to copy some CPAN module here? Why?

Comment: I'll be honest I just didn't think much ahead of why I didn't get the reference right.

Comment: Tie::IxHash is not significantly slower unless you have reorder existing keys; adding / reading / updating keys is very close to a bare hash in speed--it is measurably slower, but the difference is so insignificant that you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth: I agree wholeheartedly. In this instance, because the OP is having trouble comprehending a hash plus associated index, I would recommend a `Tie` module. Sadly, none of the CPAN modules that I know come close to the flexibility of a simple hash plus index array(s).

Answer (score 1):

Perl hashes are *inherently unordered*. There is no way you can sort them, or reorder them at all. You have to write code to to access the elements in the order you want.

Your `sortt` subroutine does nothing but print the ID and the name of each hash element, sorted by the ID. Except that it doesn't, because you are trying to use the variable `$data` when you have actually set up `$dref`. That is likely to be the cause of your `Not a HASH reference` error, although unless you show your entire code, or at least indicate which is `perlprogram.pl line 452`, then we cannot help further.

The best way to do what you want is to create an *array* of hash keys, which you can sort in whatever order you want. Like this

```
my @names_by_id = sort { $guys->{$a}{Id} <=> $guys->{$b}{Id} } keys %$guys;
```

Then you can use this to access the hash in *sorted order*, like this, which prints the same output as your `sortt` is intended to, but formatted a little more nicely

```
for my $name (@names_by_id) {
  printf "%4d: %s\n", $guys->{$name}{Id}, $name;
}
```

If you want to do anything else with the hash elements in sorted order then you have to use this technique.

Comment: The accepted answer works just fine so far. You probably wanted a $b in the second part of that sort. I wrote most of my OP by hand so there will be some errors.

Comment: @user3046061: Thank you. Your diagnosis is correct and I have fixed my post. I checked only that it would compile

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty complex data structure. If you commonly use structures like this in your program, I suggest you take your Perl programming skills up a notch, and look into learning a bit of [Object Oriented Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html).

Object Oriented Perl is fairly straight forward: Your *object* is merely that data structure you've previously created. Methods are merely subroutines that work with that object. Most methods are getter/setter methods to set up your structure.

Initially, it's a bit more writing, but once you get the hang of it, the extra writing is easily compensated by the saving is debugging and maintaining your code.

Object Oriented Perl does two things: It first makes sure that your structure is correct. For example:

```
$some_guy->{Picks}->[2]->{"this is an option"} = "Foo!";
```

Whoops! That should have been `{picks}`. Imagine trying to find that error in your code.

In OO-Perl, if I mistyped a method's name, the program will immediately pick it up:

```
$some_guy->picks(
    {
        "This is an option" -> "Foo!",
        "This is option 2"  => "Bar!",
    }
)
```

If I had `$some_guy->Picks`, I would have gotten a runtime error.

It also makes you *think* of your structure as an *object*. For example, what are you sorting on? You're sorting on your Guys' IDs, and the guys are stored in a hash called `%guys`.

```
# $a and $b are hash keys from `%guys`.
# $guys{$a} and $guys{$b} represent the guy objects.
# I can use the id method to get they guys' IDs
sort_guys_by_id {
    guys{$a}->id cmp guys{$b}->id;  #That was easy!
}
```

Take a look at the [tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html). You'll find yourself writing better programs with fewer errors.

Comment: I've read Ovid's book and it seems like default OO in Perl is a bit cumbersome and I do admit I have that in mind when I consider it. Is there any indication on how the two approaches affect speed? And how soon should I quit using plain data structures ? I've seen some code where there was one with 4 levels deep. (mine up there has 3 I think)

Comment: This isn't an answer. It is guidance along the lines of the [I wouldn't start from here joke](http://simonkidd.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/if-i-were-you-i-wouldnt-start-from-here/)

Comment: The question had been answered. The issue was the OP missed understood his own data structure, and pointed to the wrong data structure. It's a common issue when you have highly complex structures. If the OP is going to have highly complex structures, the OP should start using object oriented methods.

Comment: @user3046061 If you wrote your program two ways, with and without objects, would you be able to tell which one is faster? Probably not. Compilers are fairly good at optimization, computers are blindingly fast, and if there is a problem with the program's efficiency, its more due to algorithmic issues than with OOP vs. non-OOP. Yes, Perl OOP is a bit cumbersome, but it's not difficult, and once you learn it, you'll be able to write bigger and more complex programs.

Comment: @DavidW.: It is a hash of hashes. It is far from being *"highly complex"*

Answer (score 0):

With your heart set on a sorted data structure, I recommend the following. It is a simple array of hashes and, rather than using the `name` string as the key for a single-element hash, it adds a new `name` key to each guy's data.

I hope that, with the `Data::Dump` output, it is self-explanatory. It is sorted by the `Id` field as you requested, but it *still* has the disadvantage that a separate index array would allow *any* ordering at all *without* modifying or copying the original hash data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my $guys = {
  "SomeGuy " => {
    date_and_time => "11-04-2013",
    Id => 7,
    nr => 52,
    picks => [
      { "This is an option" => "Option3" },
      { "This is another option" => "Option4" },
      { "This is another option" => "Option1" },
      { "And another one" => "Something" },
    ],
    time_of => "06:11 AM",
    total => 1,
  },
  "Another Guy" => { Id => 9, nr => 99, total => 6 },
  "My Guy" => { Id => 1, nr => 42, total => 3 },
};

my @guys_sorted = map {
  my $data = $guys->{$_};
  $data->{name} = $_;
  $data;
}
sort {
  $guys->{$a}{Id} <=> $guys->{$b}{Id}
} keys %$guys;

dd \@guys_sorted;
```

**output**

```
[
  { Id => 1, name => "My Guy", nr => 42, total => 3 },
  {
    date_and_time => "11-04-2013",
    Id => 7,
    name => "SomeGuy ",
    nr => 52,
    picks => [
      { "This is an option" => "Option3" },
      { "This is another option" => "Option4" },
      { "This is another option" => "Option1" },
      { "And another one" => "Something" },
    ],
    time_of => "06:11 AM",
    total => 1,
  },
  { Id => 9, name => "Another Guy", nr => 99, total => 6 },
]
```

Comment: I'm not using something like this because I can't find a compelling reason for it. The structure that I went with, which is similar to the one in the accepted answer maps better to how I want to see and think of the data. Plus I end up writing less code than if I had to take your alternative, and that counts for me. Just the mere fact that it prints prettier on Data::Dump is an advantage when it comes to debugging. That always counts.